# Laravel: dependency injection of logged user?

Tags: php, laravel

Is this possible to be less boilerplate in controllers when current user must be known?

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    function index(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user(); // <------
        return Foo::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()->toArray();
    }
}
```

Is this possible to receive `$user` directly from a dependency injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so from the `Request` class

```
$user = $request->user();
```

OR - using helper functions

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

Comment: Isn't this just alternatives to what they are already doing rather than the question about getting the user automatically?

Comment: @NigelRen Indeed

Comment: Sorry if i got your question wrong, you can do a helper function to get the current user automatically like `user()`, in case of views you can use the helper method you created or use `view composers` to share the current authenticated with all views.

Answer (score -1):

in `Controller.php` you can add protected property

```php
protected $user;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = auth()->user ?? null;
}
```

then in all contoller you can do `$this->user`